# Why are small edits discouraged?

Tags: discussion

I have seen several posts here on Meta that discourage small edits (eg, remove a single superfluous tag, or remove "hello"/"thanks", or fix minor grammar, etc.). The general consensus seems to be that it's ok to fix small things, but only as part of a large comprehensive edit.

Why is this policy of discouraging small edits prevalent? Is there something fundamentally wrong with small edits?<sup>1</sup>

Consider this hypothetical:

Someone comes along and considers a large comprehensive edit to a question. The edit fixes a bunch of things, and is definitely a good edit, but the editor overlooks a small-ish typo. Had the editor noticed the typo, it should clearly have been part of the edit. But if the edit is made without fixing the typo, should another edit be discouraged because simply fixing the typo would be too small a change? Why should the additional small edit be encouraged or discouraged? If there wasn't originally a large/comprehensive edit and only the typo to consider, does the answer change?

---

<sup>1</sup> I am assuming the editor has enough rep to make the edit outright without polluting the "suggested edit" queue.

Comment: Newer users (with lower reputation) earn additional reputation by editing. Minor edits that ignore other improvements are a quick way for them to add to their reputation and earn privileges (gaming the system). Once you've gained the ability to make edits without having them reviewed first, minor edits are fine (although you should be careful doing so without making other improvements when needed).

Comment: so have a system where small edits generate less points, but at least let me make a small edit. sometimes it's important