# Is there a place where planned (or requested) changed are gathered?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I hate the "6 characters limit edit" and after reading [discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261360/trivial-edits-only-concerning-language-grammar) [on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288381/why-are-small-edits-discouraged) [the subject](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281156/are-purely-cosmetic-edits-to-original-code-frowned-upon-even-if-they-accompany) I understand the few drawbacks and multiple advantages of getting rid of the rule :)

Is there a place where such Requests For Much Needed Improvements are gathered? And possibly voted upon?

I do not care about the +2 rep when editing something which is more readable afterwards, even if it means adding two backquotes. Looking at the discussions, there are many ideas on how to improve this and other features of SO so that it becomes even more extraordinary.

**Where are they capitalized, if anywhere?**

Clarification: by "capitalize" I mean a system where requests are formalized, can be discussed, voted upon, etc. I now know there are tags but this is not really a true capitalization system for feature request (something like the [Wunderlist requests stack](http://wunderlist.uservoice.com/forums/136230-wunderlist-feature-requests))

Comment: [MSO planned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-planned) / [MSE planned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-planned)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the tag. Now, this is not really capitalization, just requests which come and go, possibly held together via a "duplicate" flag.

Comment: FYI, there are no plans to get rid of that rule. If you dislike the limitation, earn [full editing privileges.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: @Shog9: I will probably never earn 2,000 reputation points. I am not good enough and I use SO as the to-go place to find answers (and possibly ask questions). This does not mean that I do not want to make whatever I can to improve the site (which is a wonderful place). The current consensus is that it is better to keep low quality entries in the name of [put one of the reasons here]. I was looking for a place which capitalizes this consensus to possibly add some ideas.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-declined+suggested-edits

Comment: @WoJ worst case scenario you could always "rep-whore" on some easy questions to reach 2k rep and have the privilege. And I don't see this minor edit restriction as a bad thing - under 2k rep your edits need to be reviewed by 3 people, which is a waste of time if all you did was a minor edit to correct some typos.

Comment: @AndréDaniel: everything depends on the philosophy of the site. In Wikipedia for instance you have an army of people fixing stuff to make the articles nicer, more readable, etc. It would be great if the privilege of editing without review (to reduce the queue) could be granted upon request, possibly with zero rep benefits so that people like me can contribute.

Comment: As of this comment, there are only 23 suggested edits. Its not like its overflowing and things take too long. And given the amount of invalid edits that people who aren't completely familiar with the site do, its a necessary check.